# Laravel 5.4 - I can't even execute php artisan config:clear - [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

My project was working fine. After copy and pasting files in another Mac localhost, I always get the same error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>       SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database '***' (SQL: select * from `roles`)
>
> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database '***'

I already checked the `.env` file, but it seems Laravel can't execute code at this point. This 'roles' is a table with many to many relations trough pivot table.

Note 1: Fresh Laravel aplications works fine.

Note 2: Because I can't clear the cache, Laravel always considers the user to b be blank.

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: check out the database credentials in your .env files, it's too clear that there are wrong username or password

Comment: @hassan, thanks. I checked, but everything looks fine. i can't even execute php artisan config:cached

Comment: i can't clear cache... Laravel always consider user blank

Comment: After setting `.env` file delete `vendor` folder and do `composer install`. Let me know if this works

Comment: Hi @Gayan, your approuch is very interesting and I think this should work. I replaced files off a fresh application with my files and everything worked fine. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced files off a fresh application with my files(models, controllers, middlewares, migrations ...) and everything worked fine.

The solution:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-doesnt-exist/replies/151761

Answer (score 1):

If your connection string is cached it will continue to use that.

You can try clearing and rebuilding the connection and config strings with

`php artisan config:cache`

or you can clear explicitly with:

`php artisan cache:clear`

It that that does not work I think your database is not connecting for other reasons.

Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks, but i already had tried to clear cache... I'm using MySQL. I answered the question.